# Given a text file of integers corresponding to pixel values, most efficient way to implement an unsupervised learning algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning

Sorry that the title is a bit vague but I couldn't think of a more concise way to state my problem.

I have a .txt file of roughly 1500 rows and 256 columns, taken from UCI's Machine Learning repository. Each row is a vector of 256 binary values meant to represent a 16x16 scaled version of images of handwritten numbers, i.e. 0 through 9. For a full explanation you can read their full description [here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/semeion/semeion.names).

Because I had trouble visualizing what I was working with, I wrote a short Java program to draw each image from the text file. [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfLxY.jpg) an example of one of them, which would seem to be a '5'; the program simply goes down each row and colors the square if the pixel is 1.

I want to analyze this text file to teach a machine learning system how to recognize different digits. I'm taking a university course where we're learning many different machine learning techniques, but I'm not sure which would be best to apply here. I've considered an unsupervised Hebbian network, a Hidden Markov Model, k-means clustering, and a few others but with my limited knowledge I don't really know which would be the "best" (i.e., combination of easiest to implement and that which gives the lowest error rate) way to solve this problem.

I have access to MatLab as well as having downloaded lots of open-source machine learning libraries such as NeuroPH, gCLUTO and others but I'm not really sure where to begin. What would be a good technique to analyze this particular data set, and if possible, could anyone recommend a specific library or implementation of this system? Thank you!

Comment: your data has labels, thus why are you thinking about unsupervised techniques? Unsupervised methods are used when you do not have labels. Supervised will always be better (unsupervised can still be used to help supervised counterparts but not **instead**) in learning something that actually has labels.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, I'm new to the subject, but how would I implement this? I thought the whole point of supervised learning was that you specify the output you want to see given an input -- i.e., if you see some vector {v1 .. v256}, interpret that as the number '2'. But if the whole point of the data file is that the images aren't all the same, how would I write code to tell a network to choose some output given some input? Would I be better off trying to simply cluster rows by similarity (k-means/Veroni tesselation) and then assign labels myself afterwards?

Comment: Yes you need label in such setting and your data is clearly labeled. You can of course try to Just find some groups in unsupervised manner just for an exercise. If this is the case then there is no such thing as Best method. There hundreads of solutions, especially for such simple data. Try to start with any method that you understand, analyze what happens and if it is not satisfactionary try next. There is no such thing as the Best approach